# How to set a background image on web page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a Background Image which is a URL: https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png

When i try like below it is not working

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png");
  background: linear-gradient(red, pink);
}
```

Comment: first duplicate to explain how to use multiple background, second duplicate to explain the strange repeat of the gradient

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the two within `background-image`:

```css
body {
 background-image: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.52), rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73)),
   url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png");
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: sir,
I am able to get it but in the mobile view image size is not rendering correctly

Comment: You need to also use `background-position` and media queries. Check the web for many good examples

Comment: Oh ok. if you dont mind can you please help me with some example. I am not a front end guy so i dont know much about this :(

Answer (score 0):

The second line `background: linear-gradient(red, pink);` is overriding the first one.
I don't know what exactly you want to do, but remove the second line or group them like in the other answer.